# PSQL - Python - create insert statement with single quotes within query

Tags: python, string, postgresql, list, parsing

I have

```
ListA = [ ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC ] 
ListB = [ Ashley, Bob, Catherine's Book ]
```

Note that `ListB` is list of list and one of the list is the above `ListB`.

I loop over both the lists to create insert statement to execute by cursor.

Since Catherine's Book has an apostrophe, I need to add another apostrophe in order to avoid error when its read in values in insert statement.

I achieve it by

```
for i,v in enumerate(ListB): --looping over list of list of values
    for a,etc in enumerate(v): --looping over one of the list (ListB) to pass to insert statement
                            if "'" in etc:
                                etc = etc.replace("'","''")
                            else:pass
```

But it result in enclosing Catherine's Book in double quotes (") instead of single quotes.

```
insert into table1 ("ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC") 
values ('Ashley', 'Bob', "Catherine''s Book")
```

but since I get an error in PSQL, I need to make it like

```
insert into table1 ("ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC") 
values ('Ashley', 'Bob', 'Catherine''s Book')
```

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Don't do that manually. Use library to prepare query.  Gluing queries in this way is vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) .

Comment: Thank you for the nice suggestion. I will look into it too. First I need to append the string value to existing list without double quotes as I have mentioned above.

Comment: Please show this part of code, when query is build.